# Insert at start of list

Tags: c, linked-list

I am writing a simple function in c++.

I get some errors with my code. THERE is no output.

Also I need to call free after remembered where the next index.
I dont know how to do that.
Do I need to free current inside the while loop after printf?
here my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
/* these arrays are just used to give the parameters to 'insert',
to create the 'people' array
*/

#define HOW_MANY 7
char *names[HOW_MANY]= {"Simon", "Suzie", "Alfred", "Chip", "John", "Tim",
          "Harriet"};
int ages[HOW_MANY]= {22, 24, 106, 6, 18, 32, 24};

/* declare your struct for a person here */
typedef  struct{
  char*  name;
  int   age;
   struct person *next;
}
person;
static void insert( person *headptr, char *name, int age)
{
    person *ptr=malloc(sizeof(person));
            if(ptr==NULL) abort();
            //assign to structure field
    ptr->name = name;
    ptr->age = age;
            //link new object into the list
            ptr->next=headptr;
            headptr=ptr;

}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
/* declare the people array here */
person *headptr=NULL;

// Make a copy of the pointer to the head item in the list
for (int index=0;index < HOW_MANY;index=index+1)
    {
  insert(headptr, *(names+index), ages[index]);
}
person *current=NULL;

    // current will be set to NULL when it reaches the end
while(current != NULL)
    {
  // print out the item information

  printf("name: %s, age: %i\n",current -> name, current-> age);
        // Now move to the next item in the linked list
  current= current -> next;
}




}
```

Comment: `I get some errors with my code.` Let us know at least one of them.

Comment: You assign null to current and test it in a while loop.

Comment: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
     ptr->next=headptr;
              ^
lists.c: In function ‘main’:
lists.c:52:14: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
       current= current -> next;

Comment: Please indent your code to make it human readable. Also, this looks very much like C, not C++ (though it may compile with a C++ compiler)

Comment: @Walter there are things in this code that would not compile in C++, like assigning the return value of malloc() to a typed pointer without a typecast. So this is clearly C.

Comment: You haven't defined a `struct person`– you have an anonymous struct with the alias `person`. (Don't tag C code as C++. If you want to learn C++, don't write C.)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to modify your `insert` method like below:-

```
static person* insert(person *headptr, char *name, int age)
{
    if (headptr == NULL) {
        headptr = (person*)malloc(sizeof(person));
        headptr->name = name;
        headptr->age = age;
        headptr->next = NULL; 
    }
else{
    person *ptr = (person*)malloc(sizeof(person));
    if (ptr == NULL) abort();
    //assign to structure field
    ptr->name = name;
    ptr->age = age;
    //link new object into the list
    ptr->next = headptr;
    headptr = ptr;
  }
       return headptr;
}
```

And now you need to call the above method like below:-

```
// Make a copy of the pointer to the head item in the list
for (int index=0;index < HOW_MANY;index=index+1)
{
   headptr = insert(headptr, *(names+index), ages[index]);
}
```

Now you need to print your list like below:-

```
person *current=headptr;//you need to point to the first node of the list

// current will be set to NULL when it reaches the end
while(current != NULL)
{
  // print out the item information

    printf("name: %s, age: %i\n",current -> name, current-> age);
    // Now move to the next item in the linked list
  current= current -> next;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I get no output.In main method, I call insert method insert(headptr, *(names+index), ages[index]) in a for loop to through the whole list. Then I print in a for loop with condition (current = headptr; current!=NULL; current= current->next).     Maybe the headptr is null at this point, so the for loop does not run at all?

Comment: @P.Orlando, Your printing the list logic was not correct. I correct it. Now try and let me know.

Comment: You need to declare the 1st parameter of `insert()` as `person**` instead, and have the caller pass in `&headptr`. That allows `insert()` to modify the caller's variable.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, he is passing a NULL pointer at the beginning of the call. If you pass the address of a null pointer what you are going to achieve?

Comment: @Abhijit love u so much. u are my lifesaver. The problem is i did not return headptr.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, if you can not help someone with correct answer at least don't down vote a correct answer. It fixed P.Orlando's problem.

Comment: @Abhijit passing the address of the variable allows `insert()` to update the variable directly, rather than rely on the return value, which the caller is free to ignore

Comment: @RemyLebeau You could not understand what I am saying. If you send the address of a null pointer what you are going to achieve. Your suggestion is wrong until headnode is not assign with a node. As he is a new in c programming language why are you providing him a solution with pointer of pointer. Also as you down voted can you explain where I did wrong. See his comment how happy he is with my solution.

Comment: @Abhijit I understand the situation perfectly, and am well aware of how to properly implement a linked list. I down voted because your answer is error-prone and more complicated than it needs to be. The only thing you showed that I agree with is needing to initialize `current` with `headptr` instead of NULL.

Comment: It's certainly problematic that on SO the wrong answer can be accepted and the community cannot easily interfere.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code.

- Your struct's `next` field is declared using an unknown type.
- Your `insert()` function is not updating the `headptr` variable in `main()`.
- You get no output because the `current` variable in `main()` is initialized to NULL instead of `headptr`, so there is nothing for the loop to do.
- You are leaking the allocated memory.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* these arrays are just used to give the parameters to 'insert', to create the 'people' array */
#define HOW_MANY 7
char* names[HOW_MANY] = {"Simon", "Suzie", "Alfred", "Chip", "John", "Tim", "Harriet"};
int ages[HOW_MANY] = {22, 24, 106, 6, 18, 32, 24};

/* declare your struct for a person here */
typedef struct person {
    char* name;
    int age;
    struct person *next;
} person;

static void insert(person **headptr, char *name, int age) {
    person *ptr = malloc(sizeof(person));
    if (!ptr) abort();
    //assign to structure fields
    ptr->name = name;
    ptr->age = age;
    //link new object into the list
    ptr->next = *headptr;
    *headptr = ptr;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    /* declare the people array here */
    person *headptr = NULL;

    // insert items at the head of the list
    for (int index = 0; index < HOW_MANY; ++index) {
        insert(&headptr, names[index], ages[index]);
    }

    person *current = headptr;
    // current will be set to NULL when it reaches the end
    while (current) {
        // print out the item information
        printf("name: %s, age: %i\n", current->name, current->age);
        // Now move to the next item in the linked list
        current = current->next;
    }

    // free the items
    current = headptr;
    while (current) {
        person *next = current->next;
        free(current);
        current = next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To insert at the front of a linked list, I would suggest that you pass a pointer to the head of the list, not the head, resulting in something like this example (written from memory, but should work):

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct list {
  struct list *next;
  int value;
} list;

void list_push(list **phead, int value) {
  list *front = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
  front->next = *phead;
  front->value = value;
  *phead = front;
}

bool list_insert(list **phead, int value, int index) {
  list **ptr = phead;
  while (index-- > 0) {
    if (!*ptr) return false;
    ptr = &(*ptr)->next;
  }
  list_push(ptr, value);
  return true;
}

void list_dump(list *head) {
  while (head) {
    printf("%d\n", head->value);
    head = head->next;
  }
}

void main(void) {
  list *head = NULL; // empty list
  list_push(&head, 23);
  list_insert(&head, 42, 1);
  list_insert(&head, 13, 0);
  list_dump(head);
}
```